# dd returns 0 from bash, but returns an error if run with subprocess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess, dd

I am trying to run `dd` from a Python script using `subprocess.run()`. If I run the following command from my terminal, it works fine:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/file.txt bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync
```

Note: `~/file.txt` did not exists before the command, but gets created automatically.

Now, if I fire up my `python3` and do

```
cmd='dd if=/dev/zero of=~/file.txt bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync'
import subprocess
ReturnVariable = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

I get

```
dd: failed to open '~/file.txt': No such file or directory
```

This happens both if `~/file.txt` exists and if it doesn't. It doesn't make much sense anyway since it is the output file, not the input file.

What am I doing wrong? Why does the same command on the same machine not work if I call it via `subprocess.run()`?

Comment: It's not expanding the directory name `~` into your home directory.

Comment: ^ ... and you can use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to do that.

Comment: @wim how exactly can I edit my exampel to do that?

Answer (score 3):

`subprocess.run()` uses `/bin/sh` as the shell, which is probably not the same as your interactive shell (probably `bash`).

`sh` only replaces `~/` with your home directory when it's at the beginning of a word. `bash` also expands it after `=` and `:`. So `of=~/file` is expanded in `bash`, but not `sh`, so it's not expanded when you use `subprocess.run()`.

You can simply use the environment variable directly instead of tilde.

```
cmd='dd if=/dev/zero of=$HOME/file.txt bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync'
```